# symbolic link for existing directory

Tags: linux, symbolic-link

I am trying to change `/var/log` directory to symbolic link.
As `/var/log` exists, I tried as below.

```
# cd /var
# mv log log.bk                             (1)
# ln -snf /path/to/somewhere/var/log log    (2)
```

This way does not work well because a new `/var/log` directory is created between `(1)` and `(2)` ( I guess some system daemon creates it ), the symbolic link is created inside `/var/log` directory.

```
# ls -l /var/log
     :
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    23 Sep  2 13:27 log -> /path/to/somewhere/var/log
-rw-r----- 1 root adm  38028 Sep  2 13:51 messages
     :
```

My expecting is as below.

```
# ls -l /var
    :
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    23 Sep  2 13:27 log -> /path/to/somewhere/var/log
drwxr-xr-x 8 root root  1680 Sep  2 06:25 log.bk
    :
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

self resolved.

I use `mount --bind` instead of symbolic link.

```
mount --bind /path/to/somewhare/var/log log
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do what you say what you want to do
(instead of what you settled for),

1. Try it as one command line: `mv log log.bk  &&  ln -snf /path/to/somewhere/var/log log`.
2. Try it in single-user mode.